# Two way binding isn't working in a custom control (WPF)

Tags: wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

I've created a custom control, combining a label and a textbox.
I would like to bind the `Text` property to a property of a viewmodel so that property can be changed by the user.
The controls are created dynamically based on a custom attribute that a viewmodel has and are added to a grid.
Everything works as intended:

- the controls are created
- the label and textbox contain the correct values

But when I change a value, the change doesn't get reported back to the viewmodel.

When I changed the code so that a normal textbox is used instead of the custom control, everything works as intended. The problem must be found, imo, in the control

This is the code where the controls are created (in the codebehind of another control).

```
private static void OnItemToDisplayChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (DetailFormBase)d;
            control.ContentField.Children.Clear();
            Type type = control.ItemToDisplay.GetType();
            PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

            // Create a TextInput control for each property that has a DisplayNameAttribute
            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                VP.Data.DisplayNameAttribute? attribute = GetDisplayNameAttribute(type, property.Name);

// When I change the TextInput to a TextBox and use the same binding, everything works
                TextInput input = new()
                {
                    LabelText = attribute.DisplayName
                };

                var binding = new Binding(property.Name)
                {
                    Source = control.ItemToDisplay,
                    Mode = BindingMode.TwoWay,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
                };

                input.SetBinding(Controls.TextInput.ContentTextProperty, binding);

                control.ContentField.Children.Add(input);
            }
```

This is the usercontrol XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Controls.TextInput"
             x:Name="TextInputControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Controls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="100" d:DesignWidth="600" d:Background="White">

        <Grid Margin="10 5 10 5">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="2*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Label x:Name="LabelTextControl"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   FontSize="12"/>

            <TextBox x:Name="ContentTextControl"
                     Grid.Row="1" 
                     FontSize="22"
                     BorderBrush="Transparent"
                     VerticalContentAlignment="Center"                                 
                     Margin="5 0 0 5"
                     Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=ContentText,  Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        </Grid>
    
</UserControl>
```

And the code behind

```
namespace Controls
{

    public partial class TextInput : UserControl
    {
        public TextInput()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelTextProperty = 
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "LabelText", 
                typeof(string), 
                typeof(TextInput),
                new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnLabelTextChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ContentTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ContentText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TextInput),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                    string.Empty,
                    FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault | FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.Journal,
                    new PropertyChangedCallback(OnContentTextChanged),
                    new CoerceValueCallback(CoerceText),
                    isAnimationProhibited:true,
                    UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged));

        public string LabelText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(LabelTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(LabelTextProperty, value);
        }
        public string ContentText
        {
            get => (string)GetValue(ContentTextProperty);
            set => SetValue(ContentTextProperty, value);
        }


        private static void OnLabelTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (TextInput)d;
            control.LabelTextControl.Content = (string)e.NewValue;
        }   
        private static void OnContentTextChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = (TextInput)d;
            control.ContentTextControl.Text = (string)e.NewValue;
        }

        private static object CoerceText(DependencyObject d, object value)
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

            return value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: `RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent` is meant to be used on a ControlTemplate. Here you would use `RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl, ...`